# How to interpolate already translated string in Django templates?

Tags: django, templates, interpolation

I have a generic delete view that includes a confirmation question as a translated string containing one placeholder. I would like to interpolate it like this:

```
<p class="text-error">
    {% message % object %}
</p>
```

Variable `message` contains a string like: "Do you want to remove user %s?".

*How can I use string interpolation in templates?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I made a custom filter:

```
from django.template.base import Library

register = Library()

@register.filter
def interpolate(value, arg):
    """
    Interpolates value with argument
    """

    try:
        return value % arg
    except:
        return ''
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following dictionary with strings:

```
strings = { 'object': 'word' }
```

as follows:

```
{{ strings|stringformat:message }}
```

with the [stringformat](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#stringformat) filter. Note that the leading `%` is dropped from the string (see the documentation for more details).

Comment: It seems that  [stringformat](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.4.1/django/template/defaultfilters.py#L240) filter prepends `%` before the format, so the message has to have a string formatting operator at the beginning which is not always desirable. I.e. "s will be deleted. Is that OK?" will work, while "Do you want to remove user %s?" won't.

Comment: @AalexGabi: that'S not how you should use it. If you pass a dictionary then you can use `(object)` anywhere in the string to refer to it and to substitute the value `'word'`.